# quartic polynomial with no x-intercepts

Tags: polynomials

What is an example of a 4th degree polynomial with no x-intercepts. I have looked everywhere but can not find one.

Comment: Try $x^4+1$. Every **cubic** has a real root, but many quartics don't.

Comment: Note "x-intercept" means points where $y=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any quartic where terms of odd degree have zero coefficient,namely any quartic polynomial of form $f(x)=x^4+x^2+n$ where $n$ is any non-negative integer

Answer (score 0):

$y= x^4 - 12x^3 +59x^2 -138x +130$ is an example, as all of its roots are complex.

Comment: To format the equation you must put $ at each end of the equation.